# Somar linhas iguais de diferentes tabelas no R

Tags: table, data.frame, r

Estou tendo como saída diversas tabelas com três colunas, como por exemplo:

```
Inicial            Final        Mudanca
       1                 1              200
       1                 3              500
       3                 1               250
       3                 3               175
Tabela 2
   Inicial         Final        Mudanca
       1                 3              180
       1                 5              265
       3                 3               147
       3                  7              155
```

Preciso somar a última coluna das tabelas (Mudanca) de maneira que as linhas da coluna Inicial e Final da Tabela 1 seja igual a cada linha da Inicial e Final da Tabela 2, gerando uma tabela desse tipo

```
Inicial            Final        Mudanca
       1                 1          200
       1                 3           680
       1                 5           265
       3                 1            250
       3                 3            322
       3                 7           155
```

Estou tentando dessa forma, mas está dando erro:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(t1) {
  t2[t2$Inicial == row$Inicial && t2$Final == row$Final,t2$Mudanca] <- row$Mudanca + t2[t2$Inicial == row$Inicial && t2$Final == row$Final,t2$Mudanca]
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar, por gentileza?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Através de duas maneiras consegui resolver isso:

A) usando aggregate e rbind

`aggregate(Changes ~ ., rbind(t1, t2), sum)`

B) ou criando uma nova coluna com as somas:

```
joined = merge(t1,t2,by = c("Initial","Final"),all=T)
    joined["Changes.final"] <- apply(joined[,c("Changes.x","Changes.y")],
                                 FUN = function(x)sum(x,na.rm=T), MARGIN = 1)
```